# Satellite elevation angles negative

Tags: polar-coordinates, celestial-mechanics

Until recently, the code I used to calculate the elevation and azimuth of a satellite from one particular site appeared to work.
Then I used a different file from a site, not in the northern but in the southern hemisphere. The elevation angles calculated were sometimes negative i.e. the satellite was below the horizon.
This is incorrect, so either the file parameters to be used for the satellite position are false (less likely), or my code below is incorrect (more likely).

```
    rx_position = (self.X_rx, self.Y_rx, self.Z_rx)  #Given in header, in meters
    diff_position = satellite_carteisan_coords - rx_position
    diff_position_individual = diff_position[0]

    rho = np.sqrt(diff_position_individual[0]**2 + diff_position_individual[1]**2 + diff_position_individual[2]**2)

    dphi, dlambda, h = self.cartesian_to_geoid(rx_position)

    slat = np.sin(np.radians(dphi))
    slon = np.sin(np.radians(dlambda))
    clat = np.cos(np.radians(dphi))
    clon = np.cos(np.radians(dlambda))

    F = np.array([[-slon, -slat*clon, clat*clon],
                  [clon,  -slat*slon, clat*slon],
                  [0,   clat,     slat   ]])

    np.split(diff_position_individual, 3)
    local_vector = np.dot(F.T, diff_position_individual)

    E = local_vector[0]
    N = local_vector[1]
    U = local_vector[2]

    hor_dis = np.sqrt(E**2 + N**2)

    if hor_dis < 1e-20:
        Azi = 0
        Ele = 90
    else:
        Azi = np.rad2deg(math.atan2(E, N))
        Ele = np.rad2deg(math.atan2(U, hor_dis))

    if Azi < 0:
        Azi = Azi + 360 

    return Azi, Ele
```

How can I ensure that the code above does not end up calculating elevation angles that are negative?

Comment: Am I alone in thinking that this would be better suited for Stack Overflow or Code Review?

Comment: @Parcly, yes and no. It's already on stackoverflow, but I beleive it has more to do with the equations and less to do with the coding syntax. Either way, it can't harm being on both platforms.

Comment: By convention, when you cross-post a question to another platform, you should link back to the original platform.

Comment: Ooops, looks like I just broke a rule. My bad.

Comment: And here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39037435/satellite-elevation-angles-negative) (which has no answers either).